# How to Add a Time Delay Variable to DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

First I created a randomDelay value using arc4random

Then I would like to add the randomDelay value to the DispatchQueue to create a random Time Delay Variable

Here is my code:

```
func animation1() {

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {

    // various code

}, completion: { (true) in

    //delay calling the function by the randomDelay value of '0' to '2' seconds
    let randomDelay = arc4random_uniform(3)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + randomDelay) { // the randomDelay value throws an unresolved identifier 'randomDelay' error
        self.showAnimation2() // Go to the next function
    }
  })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's stopping you from replacing the `1.5` with `randomDelay`?

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, I tried this but it throws an unresolved identifier 'randomDelay' error

Comment: [Edit] your question showing your exact code causing your issue.

Comment: Your code gives me a "type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast `randomDelay` to a `Double`. Then you use it as follows:

```
let randomDelay = arc4random_uniform(3)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(randomDelay)) {
}
```

Comment: The use of `Double` converts the integer obtained from `arc4random_uniform` into a `Double` which allows you to add the value to `.now()`. You still only add 0, 1, or 2 seconds since that is the only values you will get from your use of `arc4random_uniform`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, works great - is there a way to tweak this to arrive at say 1.5 seconds, or 2.4 seconds, instead of a single whole number?

Comment: Sure. If you want a number between 0.0 and 3.0 in 1/10 second intervals, change the `3` to `31` and then change `Double(randomDelay)` to `Double(randomDelay) / 10`. This gives you a random number in the range 0 to 30 and the division by 10 gives you values in the range 0.0 to 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

You did not mention what time unit the random number is in. I suggest you select a unit. For example, seconds:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(Int(randomDelay)), execute: {...})
```

Or milliseconds:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(Int(randomDelay)), execute: {...})
```

Comment: The comments in the code in the question states the random number is in seconds. Note that `.seconds` takes an `Int` but `randomDelay` is not an `Int`.

Comment: Yup - when I try the .seconds(randomDelay) it throws aa 'ambiguous' error without more context

Comment: @ServerProgrammer I edited the code. Forgot that `arc4random_uniform` returns an `UInt32`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you!

```
let aRandomVar = 2   // change 2 to desired number of seconds
 let when = DispatchTime.now() + Double(aRandomVar)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
       // Your code with delay
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Madhur Diwan, can we swap out "let aRandomVar = 2" to "let aRandomVar = arc4random_uniform(3)"

Comment: yes, you can do so :)